# SWIG-generated code not handling or throwing exception

Tags: java, c++, swig

I am using SWIG to generate Java code from C++ code.  One of the generated files has the following compilation error:

```
acme/src/feir/api/java/abi.java:25: error: unreported exception result; must be caught or declared to be thrown
    delete();
          ^
```

Why would SWIG not generate the code to either catch or throw the exception?

This is the generated code:

```
  protected void finalize() {
    delete();
  }

  public synchronized void delete() throws result {
    if (swigCPtr != 0) {
      if (swigCMemOwn) {
        swigCMemOwn = false;
        csfeJNI.delete_procedure_flags(swigCPtr);
      }
      swigCPtr = 0;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you show the swig input file?

Answer (score 0):

You need a bunch of:

```
%nojavaexception ~classname;
```